# how to add select all for jquery formatter

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is like this

```
var columnDisplay = [{
  "name": "columnId",
  "label": "Column Id",
  "type": "string",
  hidden: true,
  "width": "200",
  key: true
}, {
  "name": "columnDisplayName",
  "label": "Column Display Name",
  "type": "string",
  "visibility": true,
  "width": "200"
}, {
  "name": "visibility",
  "label": "Visibility",
  "editable": true,
  "width": "200",
  "edittype": "checkbox",
  "editoptions": {
    value: "Y:N"
  },
  "formatter": "checkbox",
  "formatoptions": {
    disabled: false
  }
}];
```

and I call function called createJqgrid in that i have mentioned multiselect is true ..

My question is ,In my table i have a column for (visibilty) checkbox but i don't some how i'm not able to add check box for header .. i want to make them selectAll / deselectAll .  i tried to add .. but in column it disappears and I'll have to double click on that to get checkbox in column

Please help! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in the `jqGrid Option` this key:

```
 multiboxonly:true
```

Comment: tried not working .. checkbox itself is not coming up in header

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#list9").jqGrid({
    url:'server.php?q=2&nd='+new Date().getTime(),
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right"},      
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right"},       
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager9',
    sortname: 'id',
    recordpos: 'left',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    **multiselect: true,**
    caption: "Multi Select Example"
});
```

please refer to documentation here http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

just need to set "multiselect" option to "true".

Comment: I wanted add checkbox  for particular column and i have set multiselect : true in the jqGrid function .. But checkbox is not there in the header of that column .. i need add over there

Comment: createJqGrid : function(gridId, columns, gridData) { $("#" + gridId).jqGrid({datatype: 'local',data: gridData,editurl: 'clientArray',colModel: columns,loadonce: false,autowidth: true,shrinkToFit: false,rownumbers: true,multiselect: true,multiboxonly:true,cellEdit: false,toppager: true,cloneToTop: true,gridview:true,rowNum: 100,viewrecords : true,pager: "#pager" + gridId,viewsortcols: viewSort,cellsubmit: 'clientArray'  This is the code for crreatejqGrid

Answer (score 0):

```
var columnDisplay = [{
  "name": "columnId",
  "label": "Column Id",
  "type": "string",
  hidden: true,
  "width": "200",
  key: true
}, {
  "name": "columnDisplayName",
  "label": "Column Display Name",
  "type": "string",
  "visibility": true,
  "width": "200"
}, {
  "name": "visibility",
  **"label": "<input role='checkbox' type='checkbox' id='grid'>Visibility"**,
  "editable": true,
  "width": "200",
  "edittype": "checkbox",
  "editoptions": {
    value: "Y:N"
  },
  "formatter": "checkbox",
  "formatoptions": {
    disabled: false
  }
}];
```

Here we are going  to set role and type is **checkbox** .. we need to set a unique id , So that we can use that id to select all and deselect all..